# Can duplication of POSIX shebang (#!/bin/sh) when sourcing files into one piece cause problems, be it practical or in theory?

Tags: shell-script, shell, posix, shebang

I recently started to develop my Linux POSIX shell scripts in a more structured way.

---

Let me explain:

**Code [A]** is being sourced by some code [B], just some minimal example:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

# REQUIREMENTS
# none

# METHODS (public)
# none; this file when sourced sets up basic tput colors, if available
...
```

**Code [B]** is being executed, again some minimal example follows:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

# REQUIREMENTS
. /home/username/Development/sh/functions/func-color_support

# METHODS (public)
print_error ()
# this prints custom heading and a given error message
{
...
}
```

---

What I did not originally realize, because it works fine in recent versions of Bash and Dash, is that I am duplicating the shebang (`#!/bin/sh`) each time I source some of the function file(s). I am working in VS Code with self-compiled ShellCheck and the *obvious* reason for me to add the shebang is naturally wanting to edit and update the functions without having to change the syntax highlighter every time.

---

Hence my question follows:

Is duplication of the shebang (`#!/bin/sh`) violating any POSIX shell programming *rules* or *guidelines*? Further, can duplication of POSIX shebang (`#!/bin/sh`) when sourcing files into one piece cause problems, be it practical or in theory?

---

I posted this on StackOverflow yesterday and still not having an answer, but this comment seems promising:

- See 2.1.1 [here](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html), quote:

> If the first line of a file of shell commands starts with the characters "#!", the results are unspecified.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115730/discussion-on-question-by-linuxsecurityfreak-can-duplication-of-posix-shebang).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is duplication of the shebang (#!/bin/sh) violating any POSIX shell programming rules or guidelines?

I don't believe so, no. Look at the definition for `dot` on the same page:

> The shell shall execute commands from the file in the current environment.

The first line from a sourced (`dot`) file is not *the first line of a file of shell commands* because we're just adding them into the current environment. Therefore I think that your concern that "*If the first line of a file of shell commands starts with the characters "#!", the results are unspecified.*" does not apply.

> Further, can duplication of POSIX shebang (#!/bin/sh) when sourcing files into one piece cause problems, be it practical or in theory?

I myself have never seen such problems. In this context the `#` is just a comment marker.

Answer (score 2):

Not a problem. The shebang line (`#!/bin/bash`) looks like a `#`-comment to `bash`.

The `#!` is only interpreted when you start the script.

Comment: Read `man execve`, see the "`Interpreter scripts`" section. https://linux.die.net/man/2/execve